# Hamburger toggle icon is not displayed properly.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, hamburger-menu

I am trying to develop an android app which has an ActionBarDrawerToggle hamburger icon. Everything works fine but the hamburger icon is not displayed properly. Its clipped off from the top as you can see in the image. I have tried to adjust the height of the toolbar but no use. Is it something wrong with my layout file, kindly suggest. Below is my main activity file and the image file

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="com.example.xxx.zzz.MainActivity">


    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mtoolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        />

    <!-- android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/tea2"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_products"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our Products"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Buy online!"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/card_view" />





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnaCw.jpg)

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ follow this tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There was a  small mistake on my part. I needed to put the navigation view part after the coordinator layout part. On doing that it works fine. Modified code follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    tools:context="com.example.himangshugogoi.bcd.MainActivity">


    <!--<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>-->

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mtoolbar"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@layout/toolbar_layout"
        app:theme="?actionBarTheme"
        />


    <!-- android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >




        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/tea2"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_view_products"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Our Products"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Buy online!"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <include layout="@layout/card_view" />





</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_layout"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```